# Cable organisation when travelling

Tags: organization, packaging, travel, cables

When I travel, usually by air, I still haven't found a good way to organise all my cables. I tend to have both an iPod, a cell phone, some rechargeable head phones, maybe a laptop, an electric razor, and possibly some other electronic devices. This generates quite a lot of cables and small electronic devices to carry around.

To further complicate the issue you need to present most of these at the airport security, that is if you don't want to be stopped for manual security checks all the time.

So my question is: *How to organise your cables and small electronic devices when travelling?* Hopefully in some way which are easy to present at the airport security, somehow.

I've tried some variations of boxes and clear plastic bags, but please present your way of organising these items. Bonus points if they in addition are easily accessible.

Comment: I use clear plastic bags, one per cable (to prevent tangling!). On each I either write what the cable is for, or I attach a piece of silver duct tape and write the description on that. (I even do that at home!)

Comment: @BrettFromLA That sounds like a great idea! Could you post it as an answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Mooseman Will do. I wasn't going to because the OP mentions plastic bags in his last paragraph. But it really really works for me. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mentioned using clear plastic bags for your cables.  I've been doing this for years.  I use one cable per bag, to prevent tangling. (It works even better if you leave the ends sticking out of the mostly-zipped-up bag). Then I either write on the bag what the cable is, with a thick, black, permanent marker, or I slap a rectangle of silver duct tape on the plastic bag and write the cable's description on that.

[I made a video about this](https://youtu.be/iV8LMekEy20) a few years ago.

Comment: Individual clear plastic bags can be "colour coded" by putting different colour paper inside each of several bags in addition to the worded labels. Redundancy — all over again. Nice "How-To…" video. Add me to your Brett fanbase

Answer (score 0):

Zipped packaging/luggage cubes are the best way I have found for this yet. Each set often comes with a smaller one for electronics (marked with a label or icon). They make it very easy to pack and unpack, especially when you need one bag in a hurry, or you are tired. The are also the best thing I have ever used to make the most of the space in a smaller bag. Nothing stop you from marking your electronics bag with your own design.

[image: Luggage cubes]

(We travelled for seven weeks in Turkey etc with cabin/carry-on luggage and a small backpack each. We did the same in India, and watched with amusement as fellow travellers struggled with gigantic cases and extra bags.)

Tip: If you're travelling as a couple/pair etc, buy different coloured sets.

(photo was sourced from Ebay as was filtered through Google Image search for CC compliance)